# Intersection of Subgroups generating all subgroups of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say I have $H \leq G$ where $G$ is a group. Can I generate all the subgroups of $H$ by taking $H \cap K$ where $K$ is any other subgroup of $G$? That is, can all subgroups of $H$ be written as the intersection of $H$ with a subgroup of $G$?

I am working on a related problem and have this as a "lemma" might help. Thanks!

Comment: Just because the intersection is trivial between two subgroups doesn't necessarily imply that it is trivial for all subgroups?

Comment: If $H'$ is a subgroup of $H$, then it is also a subgroup of $G$, and taking $K = H'$ gives $H \cap K = H \cap H' = H'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivially true and doesn't really require a separate lemma, unless I'm misunderstanding. Note that any subgroup of $H$ is already a subgroup of $G$, so there's no reason to consider subgroups not entirely contained in $H$ for this question.

Comment: The question was inteneded for subgroups not contained in $H$ but that was not clear when I asked.

Comment: @az89 Then it's trivially false. Take $H=G$. If that's not a counterexample then you need to edit your question to make it clearer. As it currently is this answer answers it.